How can I change the z coordinate of a view along with zoom animation to achieve an interpolated shadow?
I want to achieve a hover effect where a button gets a zoom animation and the z coordinate increases to get a shadow.  Is this possible?  I want the shadow to be interpolated with the zoom, not just a finishing shadow.  It is my understanding if you increase the z-coordinate of a view, Android will automatically render a drop shadow.
I have the following zoom animation, R.anim.zoom_in.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:duration = "80"
        android:fromXScale = "1"
        android:fromYScale = "1"
        android:pivotX = "50%"
        android:pivotY = "50%"
        android:toXScale = "1.031"
        android:toYScale = "1.031"/>
</set>


Your current animation just scales the button, doesn't increase the z coordinate.

I don't know how to define an animated z coordinate.  That is the crux of my question.

The property you are looking for is elevation. You can use material state list animator xml file in your view as follow:
android:stateListAnimator="@animator/m3_btn_elevated_btn_state_list_anim"

